# Allowed syntax for in-line if statements

Tags: python, syntax

Sometimes I like to abuse the python syntax, specially with short `if` blocks:

```
if True : print 'Hello'
else    : print 'Bye'
```

Now I have tried to do the same with a function definition:

```
if True : def a(): return 'a'
else    : def a(): return 'b'
print a()
```

But surprisingly I can not do that:

```
  File "xxx.py", line 1
    if True : def a(): return 'a'
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The following (equivalent to me, but not to python) version is just fine:

```
if True :
    def a(): return 'a'
else    :
    def a(): return 'b'
print a()
```

Why? There seems to be a rule on what can I put inline in an `if` statement. Maybe no colon is allowed after the if-colon? Where is this rule specified? Or maybe I am breaking a more general rule? Which one?

Comment: You cannot do this because block level statements need to be indented; `def` starts a block, which is why you get that error, and `print` doesn't which is why it works. Why don't you try to describe the _actual problem you are trying to solve_ instead of asking for help with the solution.

Comment: It is just a question about syntax. The problem that I am trying to solve is "understand why a function definition can not be inlined in an if statement, while other statements are perfectly allowed". I know a dozen workarounds to solve the real problem I want to solve, but I still want to understand the syntax issue.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: one-liner compound statements are perfectly legal, cf the FineManual - what's illegal is having 2 compound statements on the same line. Also, the OP question is perfectly clear to me: he just wants to know more about what's legal syntax and where it's specified.

Comment: I did not say anything about compound statements, I said block level statements - anyway, the OP's actual problem is stated in a comment: "Anyway, for more background: I want to define the function depending on some global setting during parse time; since the function has an effect on performance, it must be as simple as possible." - so the question seems to be how to define a function at runtime properly; and the OP is asking about some syntax rules.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: my question **is** about syntax. I know how to solve my real problem in other ways. I have **posted** one such way in the original question: do not inline the `def` with the `if`. *Now* I know why I can not inline the `def` (not because of your contribution, I must say). My real problem was solved long before asking the question, that is why I didn't mention it in the question ...since I was not looking for an answer to that. Seems reasonable? The fact that you *already* know that defs can not be inlined with ifs, does not make this question invalid. Other people do not know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the syntax of `if` here http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#if

According to the syntax `if` allows

```
"if" expression ":" suite
```

and `suite` is defined as

```
suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
```

`stmt_list` is defined as

```
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

`statement` is defined as

```
stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
```

`compound_stmt` is defined as

```
compound_stmt ::=  if_stmt
               | while_stmt
               | for_stmt
               | try_stmt
               | with_stmt
               | funcdef
               | classdef
               | decorated
```

We see that `funcdef` is one of the `compound_stmt`. So, in the `if` condition, if we have to define a function, `def` has to have a `NEWLINE` and `INDENT` before that. That is why what you are trying is NOT valid.

But how about this nice and simple way

```
def a():
    return "a" if True else "b"
```

Comment: I *know* how to define the function. I just want to know why I can not do it as I wanted to. Anyway, for more background: I want to define the function depending on some global setting during parse time; since the function has an effect on performance, it must be as simple as possible.

Comment: According to the syntax definition: `"if" expression ":" suite`. But I still do not know why a `def` is not allowed in `suite`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax rules are defined here : http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html

Note that while technically legal, multiple statements on a same line are considered bad style (cf pep08).

Comment: Yep, I know I am abusing the syntax (as mentioned in the question). I still like to put short statements in a single line, sorry. Python allows for it, so I use it.

Comment: Python let you do a lot of things that you probably should not do. Now as long as I don't have to maintain your code, well, that's your problem isn't it ?-)

Comment: Ah, coding style! such an interesting topic! :) I am quite sure my coding style would make most of you cringe, but I like it!

Answer (score 1):

Its giving you an error because its now allowed by the grammar. Below are only relevant parts of the grammar.

```
if_stmt     ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
suite       ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE 
stmt_list   ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
simple_stmt ::=  expression_stmt
                 | assert_stmt
                 | assignment_stmt
                 | augmented_assignment_stmt
                 | pass_stmt
                 | del_stmt
                 | print_stmt
                 | return_stmt
                 | yield_stmt
                 | raise_stmt
                 | break_stmt
                 | continue_stmt
                 | import_stmt
                 | global_stmt
                 | exec_stmt
```

If you see from the definition above, there's no "[funcdef](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-funcdef)", which is defined like below:

```
funcdef     ::=  "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")" ":" suite
```

---

Python's syntax is beautiful, why try to make it ugly, just to conserve some lines? :)

Comment: The real reason I do it is not to save lines: it is because a nice aligned if-else block is much more legible to me that a a big block with several indentation levels. I align it manually, and it is *very* legible to me, at a glance. I can spot errors, see differences in the `elif` statements, add new cases with minimum hassle, all much faster than by using the accepted convention of putting one statement per line. This is the only case where I differ from the accepted convention, and I will stick to it.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the reply, which clarifies things. Same as @thefourtheye, therefore just upvoting :(

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot have a suite-starting in a statement you put inline instead of a suite.

For example

```
if 1: 2
```

is valid, but

```
if 1: if 2: 3
```

is not valid.

Just don't use code on the same line except extremely simple cases.

Aim is at code that is easier to read, not shorter to write.